# A cell is equal to Multiple numbers present in an IF statement, excel

Tags: excel

I have a cell, and in this cell I can cycle through 1 to 15. I need another cell to check if that cell has any of these numbers: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13, and 15. If true, it outputs a 1. I couldn’t find nay examples for my specific problem, and I don’t really understand, so I need some help.

I have looked it up, but couldn’t understand it, and they don’t have g specific problem

`=IF(B13=(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15),1)` this won’t work, but I imagine it to be something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are all the ODD numbers:

```
=IF(ISODD(B13),1,0)
```

If you want specific numbers:

```
=IF(OR(B13={2,4,6,7}),1,0)
```

If 1 and 0 are your desired outputs we can remove the IF:

```
=--OR(B13={2,4,6,7})
```

Comment: Alright, but heat if the numbers were 2,3,6, and 7?

Comment: @Tortee2 if this answered you question, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Checks if the number is odd (based on the numbers you provided) and is below or equal to 15.

```
=IF(AND(ISODD(B13),B13<=15),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could put the numbers you are checking for in a Select Case statement:

```
Sub CheckCell()

Dim ckNum As Integer
ckNum = Range("E25").Value

Select Case ckNum
Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15
    Range("F25").Value = 1
Case Else
    Range("F25").Value = 0
End Select

End Sub
```

Then you can check for any numbers you want.